# Dart Editor: It didnt work?

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I launched Dart Editor yesterday but it didn't work giving the error:

> ("A Java Runtime(jre) or Java Development Kit(jdk) must be avaible in
>   order to run DartEditor. No Java virtual machine was found after
>   searching the following loacations:
>
> C:\Users\name\Donwloads\darteditor-windows-x64\dart\jre\bin\javaw.exe 
>   jawaw.exe in your current PATH ")

Do you think how i going to fix this error ? 
Thanks

Comment: Is Dart Editör some kind of heavy metal version of the editor?

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the error message is telling you the right problem?

Comment: Try this. 1. Uninstall Java from your system. 2. Install Java 32-bit. 3. Download, unpack and run Dart Editor 32-bit for Windows. That's all. Don't use Java 64-bit for Dart Editor.

Answer (score 2):

**Checkout this link:**

*https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/troubleshoot.html*

**"Launching Dart Editor"**

Your Java version should have the same bit width as your Dart Editor version. For example, if you're using a 64-bit Dart Editor, then you should use 64-bit Java. Otherwise, you might see a message like this when you try to launch Dart Editor:

```
Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jre6\\bin\client\jvm.dll
```

To determine which version of Java you are running, do one of the following:

1-Go to CMD type java -version.
2-Go to Start -> Programs and Features.

Specifying the Java runtime

If necessary, you can specify the Java runtime that Dart Editor uses. Go to your Dart installation directory and add the following two lines to DartEditor.ini immediately before the existing ‑vmargs line:

```
-vm
/full/path/to/java
```

Important: On Windows, use double backslashes (\) as the directory separator:

```
-vm
c:\\bin\\java_jdk1.7.0\\bin\\javaw.exe
```

For example, DartEditor.ini might have:

```
-vm
/usr/local/buildtools/java/jdk-64/bin/java
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to download the Java Development SDK and your Java version should have the same bit width as your Dart Editor version. For example, if you're using a 64-bit Dart Editor, then you should use 64-bit Java. Otherwise, you might see a message like this when you try to launch Dart Editor:

You can download it here:
    http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=otnjp

and specify the java/bin directory in the darteditor.ini file.you can specify the Java SDK that Dart Editor uses. Go to your Dart installation directory and add the following two lines to DartEditor.ini immediately before the existing ‑vmargs line:

```
-vm
/full/path/to/java
```

Important: On Windows, use double backslashes () as the directory separator:

```
-vm
c:\\bin\\java_jdk1.7.0\\bin\\javaw.exe
```

For example, DartEditor.ini might have:

```
-vm
/usr/local/buildtools/java/jdk-64/bin/java
-vmargs
```

If it still doesn't work then you can follow this:
    https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/troubleshoot.html

Answer (score 0):

I made jre folder in my dart program folder.
And loaded there latest JRE. (Java runtime environment) 
It stays in every new darteditor installation.

Better / right way would maybe be using path clause...
I dont know how to.. / dont want to use it.
My choise might need to load new version of jre now and then.
Hope this helps you...